# Remove an element from observableArray inside another observableArray in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

After finishing knockout tutorial [working with lists and collections](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections) I decided to go a little bit further to implement two level nesting with knockout.

The structure of my ViewModel looks like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.elements = ko.observableArray([{
        id: 1,
        txt: 'first',
        el: ko.observableArray(['first', 'second'])
    },{
        id: 2,
        txt: 'second',
        el: ko.observableArray(['first', 'third'])
    },{
        id: 3,
        txt: 'third',
        el: ko.observableArray(['fourth', 'fifth'])
    }]);

    this.remove = function(el){
        console.log(el);
    }
}
```

So this is like Observable array in observable array. And I am outputting this with a simple 2 foreach view-binding:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: elements">
    <span data-bind="text: txt"></span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: el">
        <li data-bind="text: $data, click: $root.remove">
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is with remove statement ([full code is in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/3kk72/)). With what I have so far I am failing to delete the element. Function gives me only the value of the element I want to delete like `first` which is not enough to uniquely identify what exactly do I need to delete (is this first in the first array or the second).

So is there a way to correctly remove the element from observableArray inside of observableArray?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/3kk72/7/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass [additional arguments to the `click` handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-2-accessing-the-event-object-or-passing-more-parameters) like the `$parent` which is the [parent context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html):

```html
<li data-bind="text: $data, click: function() { $root.remove($data, $parent) }"/>
```

Then in your `remove` you can access the parent collection through the second argument and remove the current element from it:

```
this.remove = function(data, parent){
    parent.el.remove(data);
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpkRn/).

Comment: And for solve problem with same alements in nested array: http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/uJ5kV/