# html5 drag and drop files from desktop with knockout

Tags: html, knockout.js, drag-and-drop, ko.observablearray

I am trying to implement drag and drop files from desktop using knockout. The starting code is taken from [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-selecting-files-dnd).

I tried to implement this using [event binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html), so my View looks something like this:

```
<div class="drop_zone" data-bind="event:{
    dragover:   function(data, e){ $root.dragover(e);},
    drop:       function(data, e){ $root.drop(e, $parent);},
    dragenter:  function(data, e){ $root.dragenter(e);},
    dragleave:  function(data, e){ $root.dragleave(e);}
}">Drop files here</div>
```

The `$parent` parameter was used in attempt to do something similar to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22127448/1090562), where parent was able to locate where exactly the element should be removed.

My ViewModel is an observableArray of observableArrays (many dropzones) and looks like this:

```
this.dropZones = ko.observableArray([{
    'elements' : ko.observableArray([])
},{
    'elements' : ko.observableArray([])
}]);
```

The full code can be found in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/3dMHp/2/), but the problem is that I can not properly add new files to the files element. Also I can not correctly highlight the element the person is `dragEntering/Leaving`.

I understand why I can not highlight the proper element (I just select every class, but I can not understand how to select the parent element), I am failing to understand why `parent.elements.push(f.name);` does not add the name of the file to the right parent.

Can anyone please tell me what is the problem and how can I fix it?

**P.S. in jsFiddle** I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataTransfer' of undefined

which tells me that I am passing wrong event, but the same code on my local server does not give me this problem. The error which I am getting on localhost is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

which tells me that my idea of using parent was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `{ $root.drop(e, $data);}` instead of `{ $root.drop(e, $parent);}`

2) `var files = e.dataTransfer.files;` (without `originalEvent`)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JBJd2/1/). (I've not fixed problem with css, do it youself :))

You should use `$data` instead of `$parent` because of `elements` is the property of each dropZone element. So, when you iterate with `foreach: dropZones` you have access to current element by `$data`, and you should send to `$root.drop` function current element (not parent) for get access to it `elements` array.

**Update:**
[Solved CSS problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/N9T8N/1/). (with help of `$index()` and jQuery `.eq()`)

You could read about binding context (parent, data, index and etc.) [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).